# Issue in calculating amount while calling dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

below is my order form where i am taking inputs for item count. On the basis of that , dynamically Input boxe comes for quantity and rates .. Now whenever user enters quantity and rate, amount should be calculated correspondingly and displayed in amount textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <script>
        function addItemDetails() {
            var itemCount = document.getElementById("item_count").value;
            var itemDetailsDiv = document.getElementById("item_details");

            itemDetailsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous item details

            for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                var itemDetailHTML = `
                    <div>
                        <h3>Item ${i}</h3>
                        <label for="item_name_${i}">Item Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="item_name_${i}" required>
                        
                        <label for="qty_${i}">Qty:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="qty_${i}" min="1" required>
                        
                        <label for="rate_${i}">Rate:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="rate_${i}" min="0.01" step="0.01" required>
                        
                        <label for="amount_${i}">Amount:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount_${i}" readonly>
                    </div>
                `;
                itemDetailsDiv.innerHTML += itemDetailHTML;
            }
        }
        $(".rate_${i}").bind("blur", calculateAmount);
        function calculateAmount(itemIndex) {
            //document.write(5+6);
            var qty = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName(`qty_${itemIndex}`)[0].value);
            var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName(`rate_${itemIndex}`)[0].value);
            var amount = qty * rate;
            document.getElementsByName(`amount_${itemIndex}`)[0].value = amount.toFixed(2);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Order Form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="process_order.php">
        <label for="customer_name">Customer Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="customer_name" required><br>
        
        <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile_number" required><br>
        
        <label for="item_count">Item Count:</label>
        <input type="number" name="item_count" id="item_count" min="1" onchange="addItemDetails()" required><br>
        
        <div id="item_details"></div>
        
        <button type="submit">Submit Order</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having issues while calling `calculateAmount` function- when should it call? if i provide on change function also for `qty`, it is not working.

and further how would i pass index to calculate amount function?
Please help !!

Comment: Why are you not including the jQuery library in your code? After you include it then you'd get a second error in the console for `$(".rate_${i}").bind("blur", calculateAmount);` ***Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .rate_${i}***. Also, use `.on()` method instead of `.bind()`

Comment: I dont know how to use jquery library ! can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure I can: `$(".rate_${i}")` is jQuery syntax. Not plain JavaScript. If you don't want to use jQuery (not needed nowadays) then use `document.querySelector(".rate_${i}").addEventListener("blur", calculateAmount);` - but clearly, not outside the desired funtion and loop block.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly at which place it should be used?

Comment: In the same block of code where you use all the other `${i}`

Comment: Another problem: To use `${i}` you have to write a template literal, not an ordinary string. Template literals use backticks instead of quotes as the delimiters.

Comment: I have tried using it ! Can you check here ? https://jsfiddle.net/nsf9gr4m/

Comment: @Barmar woops great catch. Eagle eyes. Yes, there's also missing backticks

Comment: The `.` prefix in a selector is for class. You don't have `class="rate_${i}"` in your HTML.

Comment: Don't bind a separate click handler to each input. Just give them all `class="rate"`, and then use `$(".rate").click(calculateAmount)`

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should be using `.on()`.

Comment: I really think overall the above code needs a complete rewrite. Not sure if it's just easily salvageable by just fixing here and there...

Comment: Since you're adding these dynamically, you should use event delegation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Can you guys please help me in jsfiddle. I have change blur to on, class is added. still not working

Comment: @Barmar OP is actually not using jQuery at all. That line was most likely a remnant from another source.

Comment: Also notice that you use the `for=""` attribute wrongly. `for` should be related to an Input's `is`, not to the `name`. Actually the `for` is not needed at all if you wrap input in the label element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a bunch of updates.

First, I'm using `[name^='']` a lot in my CSS selectors. This will allow you to delegate the event handler to a function that only needs to be created once and will respond to dynamic fields.

Then when the rate is inputted, I grab the closest div as that becomes the "group" where all of the other fields are children of. Then I simply use find on that group to find the related fields.

```js
$(document).on("input","[name^='rate_']", calculateAmount);
      $("[name='item_count']").on("input",addItemDetails);
      
        function calculateAmount(e) {
           const group = $(this).closest("div");
           const qty = parseFloat(group.find("[name^='qty_']").val());
           const rate = parseFloat(group.find("[name^='rate_']").val());
           group.find("[name^='amount_']").val((qty * rate).toFixed(2));
        }
        
        

function addItemDetails() {
            var itemCount = document.getElementById("item_count").value;
            var itemDetailsDiv = document.getElementById("item_details");

            itemDetailsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous item details

            for (var i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                var itemDetailHTML = `
                    <div>
                        <h3>Item ${i}</h3>
                        <label for="item_name_${i}">Item Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="item_name_${i}" required>
                        
                        <label for="qty_${i}">Qty:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="qty_${i}" min="1" required>
                        
                        <label for="rate_${i}">Rate:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="rate_${i}" min="0.01" step="0.01" required>
                        
                        <label for="amount_${i}">Amount:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount_${i}" readonly>
                    </div>
                `;
                itemDetailsDiv.innerHTML += itemDetailHTML;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Order Form</h2>
    <form method="post" action="process_order.php">
        <label for="customer_name">Customer Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="customer_name" required><br>
        
        <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile_number" required><br>
        
        <label for="item_count">Item Count:</label>
        <input type="number" name="item_count" id="item_count" min="1" required><br>
        
        <div id="item_details"></div>
        
        <button type="submit">Submit Order</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you also help me with process_order.php ? where i am calculating total of all the amounts calculated here?